# What is reversible automaton and how it works?

Tags: reversible-computing

I have not understood how reversibility works in case of an automaton. Kindly explain.

Comment: Did you try reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_cellular_automaton ?

Comment: Here is a reference to a notion of symmetric computation: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397582900585

Comment: I once considered the following notion of symmetric finite automata: A symmetric finite automaton "is an NFA satisfying the following. Each alphabet character $c$ has a corresponding alphabet character $c^r$ such that if there is a transition from state $p$ to $q$ with alphabet character $c$, then there is a transition from state $q$ to $p$ with alphabet character $c^r$."